# How to parse Poloniex Json into VB Net Object?

Tags: json, vb.net, api

I'm currently pulling in the Poloniex returnCompleteBalances info in the following JSON format:

{"LTC":{"available":"5.015","onOrders":"1.0025","btcValue":"0.078"},"NXT:{...} ... }

I am trying to add the info to a class I made, and separate the different coins(property names) and their associated info. So far I have the following:

```
Sub GetBalances()
    Dim method As String = calldata("returnCompleteBalances")
    Dim allData As JObject = JObject.Parse(method)
    Dim coinlist As New List(Of balancedata)
    For Each token As JToken In allData("objects")
        Dim prop As JProperty = token
        coinlist.Add(New balancedata With {.Coin = prop.Name, .available = prop.Value("available"), .onOrders = prop.Value("onOrders"), .btcValue = prop.Value("btcValue")})
    Next
End Sub
```

And the class

```
Public Class balancedata
Public Property Coin As String
Public Property available As Decimal
Public Property onOrders As Decimal
Public Property btcValue As Decimal
```

End Class

When I run the code, I receive an error on the for each token as Jtoken line that reads: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

How do I resolve this? I do not know all of the values for the property name, LTC, BTC, etc. so I am trying to look through them all and itemize the associated values into a list.

Comment: JSON is JSON - it doesnt matter where it comes from.  If you are after several elements it would probably be better to deserialize it.

Comment: ok so once I deserialize it, how do I get it into a format that is easily readable? I really just want it to be in a datatable on my form

Comment: Once you deserialize - provided you use a class matching the JSON - it will put the data into those class properties.  It will make a collection of them if there is more than one item in the JSON

Comment: the issue I'm trying to get my head around, is how do I make a class that matches the JSON if i don't each property name? Wouldn't I need each to have the same name like "ID" or something? Right now there are a bunch of different coin names and no ID identifier.